# What is this strange shadow that surrounds questions sometimes?

Tags: support

Rarely, when the comment box is focused, some questions get surrounded with a strange shadow with a long width, like this:

[image: shadow around question]

What is this and why is this happening?

I am using Safari 12603.3.8 and macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Looks like you've activated keyboard shortcuts...

Comment: *only the shadow knows*

Comment: It's the Grey veil of Cody.