# Where did the info about the expandable usercards go?

Tags: support, privileges, user-card

Lately, I was looking at my next Privilege again (1.000 rep), and this time I only saw "See votes".
[image]

And when clicking on the privilege itself, the information about expandable usercards seem to be gone entirely.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Yet I still see the expandable usercards appearing on users above 1k. So the function is not removed.

Did the requirements change recently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The privilege information was removed because [expandable user cards are now universally available to everyone, regardless of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334941/can-we-make-the-expanded-user-card-privilege-universal/342575#342575):

> I am happy to announce that hover cards are now working for all users. We have removed the rep requirement for this (previously 1000 rep), so it will show for any user. Based on your feedback, we have also moved down the content requirement for showing the hover card from 28 characters to 6 characters. This is now live on all sites on the network, and relevant wiki pages have been updated.
>
> –Yaakov Ellis, a Stack Overflow developer

Comment: It appears not noticed that was done. Well, *good*. The expandable usercards was honestly a really strange privilege to only give to some people. I always felt it should have been available to all or *if it needs gating off*, then something like 5-10 rep would grant it.

Comment: I don't know about you, @VLAZ, but I'm sad to see [my distinctive Gray veil](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355301/what-is-this-strange-shadow-that-surrounds-questions-sometimes#comment505638_355301) go.

Comment: If it helps, the MetaSO logo as well as a lot of the common colours used like tag backgrounds, and quote highlight are all Gray. This *your* stack :P